# Having problems with empty arrays when recieving Json string

Tags: c#, json, rest

Getting this error when trying to convert Json properties to C# properties. precondition is an array that most of the times will be null otherwise it will be an array with no entries. The same goes for List values (KvpDTO is basicly a dictionay, it is an object with id and value).

"Body: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: ​. Path 'form.sections[0].children[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBUxl.png).type_settings.preconditions', line 42, position 0."

[left side properties, right side postman JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBUxl.png)

Comment: 1) preconditions is a list and can be null 2) the preconditions in you json is an empty array and not null (which should also work). I suspect as the error says there is an invalid character there, possibly a hidden one.

Comment: You're right, apperently there was a bunch of spaces in the array. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Empty spaces in array from json caused error.